# Como limpar uma área do canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Criei uma função que vai gerando objetos aleatórios na área `canvas` e queria que após o término dessa função a área fosse limpa.

Existe alguma possibilidade de fazer isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

---

Referência:

- http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/advanced/html5-clear-canvas/index.php

Comment: Muito obrigado @Gabriel! [OFF TOPIC] Você sabe se existe a possibilidade de adicionar eventos aos meus elementos dentro do canvas?

Comment: @Odair Dê uma olhadinha nesse artigo, no final da página: http://diveintohtml5.com.br/canvas.html Aqui explica como fazer um joguinho com canvas adicionando eventos, etc.

Comment: Valeu @Gabriel!

Answer (score 2):

```
context.clearRect(A, B, C, D);
```

A: ponto no eixo X onde se iniciará a limpeza.

B: ponto no eixo Y onde se iniciará a limpeza.

C: Limite no eixo X até onde será limpo.

D: Limite no eixo Y até onde será limpo.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Obs: Dessa forma vc limpará a partir do ponto X = 0  e  Y = 0, até a extremidade do seu `canvas`, que é `canvas.width` e `canvas.height`.